# How to extract data from 3d numpy array for 3d plot?

Tags: python, numpy

I often come across the situation where I have some 3d numpy array:
`data = np.random.rand(10, 10, 5)`, i.e. we have 5 `10x10` images stacked in the z direction. Now I would like to use `ax.scatter3d()` which requires that I have `xdata, ydata, zdata` and `cdata`. In this case `cdata` is the color data corresponding to the values in the `data` array. What is the pythonic way to go from `data` to `xdata, ydata, zdata` and `cdata`?

Comment: Do you care about the z-position of each image, or do you just want to have each image in a horizontal plane with the color representing the image data?

Comment: What do you mean by z-position? I would like `data[:, :, 0]` to be the first image displayed, then `data[:, :, 1]` to be placed behind it, etc...

Comment: I'm asking for you clarify "behind it" in your comment. You want a 3-dimensional plot. What does the z-axis correspond to? The color of each pixel? Or do you not care about that, you just want each image on top of one another?

Comment: The z-axis corresponds to a `10x10` image in my example. The greyscale value of the pixel at location `(x,y,z)` should be `data[x,y,z]`.